# How to get replSetName before exec rs.initiate() in mongodb replica set

Tags: mongodb

Because I want to write a script to batch initialize replica set,but the config _id need be the same as startup command --replSet. When I use mongo shell js script to initiate, can not get replica set name of startip command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the startup replSet option with [getCmdLineOpts](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/getCmdLineOpts/) from inside the service even the replicaSet was not initialized yet , example:

```
db.adminCommand( { getCmdLineOpts: 1  } ).parsed.replication.replSetName
myExampleRset
```